# QTableView + QFileSystemModel not sorting when setSortingEnabled(True)

Tags: python, windows, qt5, pyqt5, qtableview

Consider the below snippet:

```
import sys
import os
import time

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class Foo(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, path, extensions, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        model.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Files)
        model.setNameFilterDisables(False)
        self.setModel(model)

        self.setShowGrid(False)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

        self.change_path(path)

        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def change_path(self, path):
        model = self.model()
        index = model.index(str(path))
        self.setRootIndex(model.index(os.path.dirname(str(path))))
        self.scrollTo(index)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    file_view = Foo(__file__, ["*.*"])
    file_view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For some reason when i click on the headers the rows won't be sorted, why is that?

Docs says:

> void QTableView::setSortingEnabled(bool enable) If enable is true,
>   enables sorting for the table and immediately trigger a call to
>   sortByColumn() with the current sort section and order 
>   Note: Setter function for property sortingEnabled.  See also isSortingEnabled().

Comment: I have tested your code and I see that it works correctly, I have tested it with PyQt 5.10, in the following link there are several images that prove the reordering: https://imgur.com/a/mTuEg

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the effort! thanks to some guys from #pyqt i've been able to discover what was the problem... it took me almost 1 hour to narrow down this one, it was a really hard one as i'd tried already quite a lot of things without considering `QDir.rootPaht()` at all :/, anyway, ty.

Comment: Qt handles a generic format, so it is always advisable to use the methods that Qt offers for the routes, you should indicate the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in this case was the fact that `QDir.rootPath()` is giving `C:/` by default and the initial path i was using was located in `D:`, so to make it work you need to be sure setRootPath will match the initial path:

ie: Change `model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())` by `model.setRootPath('D:/')` and it'll work just fine. Or even better, extract the letter from the initial path so you don't hardcode anything.